# Make colon appear even though you execute a silent command

Tags: command-line

I have this remap in my vimrc which makes the cooperation between vim and bash a lot easier:

```
function! LoadRegisters()
  let $y = @0
  let $r = @"
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> : :call LoadRegisters()<enter>:
```

Basically I can just and use my internal registers in external commands without thinking about it.
However, now, whenever I use the colon I'm confused because the colon doesn't appear at the bottom, well, because it's silent.
Can I somehow make the function call silent, and then go unsilent again?

I don't know how to tag this...

Comment: I don't know if it would help, but you could try: `nnoremap : @=LoadRegisters()<CR>:` or `nnoremap <expr> : LoadRegisters().':'`. You would need to add the instruction `return ''` at the end of your function `LoadRegisters()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LoadRegisters()` function doesn't output anything, so you could remove the `<silent>`, which causes the last colon to be displayed immediately:

```
nnoremap : :call LoadRegisters()<enter>:
```

If for some reason you see any output from this function, you could try the [`:silent`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3asilent) command on the function call:

```
nnoremap : :silent call LoadRegisters()<enter>:
```

---

**Edit:**

> The thing is that I see it being typed, whenever I use the colon

For some reason I only see the last colon. Maybe you have some configuration that changes the behavior; try testing it in vanilla Vim: `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`.

Comment: The thing is that I see it being typed, whenever I use the colon, which I can live with, but if there's a way to avoid it, I'd like to do just that. Your second suggestion seems to help, but it's not perfect.

Comment: @hgiesel I included a suggestion in the answer. If that doesn't solve the issue: have you tried on both terminal and GUI (gVim)? Which Vim version?